# Silverstripe module - Facebook Authentication

Tags: php, facebook, module, openid, silverstripe

I was working with facebook authentication module, trying to log in using facebook but its seems like its not working. When I try to click the button it ask permission and stuff like that in the facebook site and then redirects back to my site but it seems like nothing happens (didn't logged in) but there are some sessions that I can see using firebug. I am working in my localhost. Is that the cause of it? I tried to log in manually and try to click the button and what it does is log out. I check my facebook id and facebook name in the database and seems to be correct.

Just to add some more information. If I am already logged in and if I use the Javascript its seems to connect to the facebook otherwise if I am logged out its similar to the senario above.

By the way I'm not very good with Silverstripe and php. Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: Am I doing this right?

```
 <form id="FacebookLoginForm_LoginForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post" action="Security/LoginForm">
                        <p id="FacebookLoginForm_LoginForm_error" class="message" style="display: none"></p>
                        <fieldset>
                            <input type="hidden" value="FacebookAuthenticator" name="AuthenticationMethod" id="FacebookLoginForm_LoginForm_AuthenticationMethod" class="hidden AuthenticationMethod">
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="Actions">
                            <input type="image" alt="Sign in with Facebook" title="Sign in with Facebook" src="facebook/Images/signin.png" name="FacebookLoginForm_dologin" id="FacebookLoginForm_LoginForm_action_Facebook_dologin" class="action">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: are you talking about https://github.com/wilr/silverstripe-facebookconnect ?

Comment: No. I am talking about this http://www.silverstripe.org/facebook-authentication-module/

Answer (score 0):

Simon Welsh of New Zealand company Pocket Rent created a module to allow login via Facebook - it adds an extra tab to the login page.  I added a tidier read me and fixed a few minor issues.  See https://github.com/gordonbanderson/facebook-auth/commits/development

Simon's original can be found here in a subversion repository, http://svn.rentbox.co.nz/public/facebook/

Comment: tried but still got the same problem. It won't log in. Please see the first post for the codes.